# Store NSInteger in Core Data

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsnumber, nsinteger

Is there any way I can skip dealing with NSNumber and work directly with NSInteger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Data will only allow NSNumbers. However, you can write custom getters and setters to use NSInteger properties. [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) is a wonderful tool that does that automatically for you: it generates classes with native properties for all your entities.

Comment: Also in the current version (4.3.2 as of this comment) of Xcode, you can check the box when generating NSManagedObject subclass to "use scalar properties for primitive data types" -- which will cause the compiler to "just know" to make the synthesized accessors promote/demote to/from NSNumber and the proper scalar. For instance, "Integer 32" will be declared as int32_t in your generated .h file, and you can simply assign integers to the property in your code.

Answer (score 2):

No. `NSInteger` is just a typedef for a long integer, not an object.

Actual implementation:

```
#if __LP64__ || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
  typedef long NSInteger;
  typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
  typedef int NSInteger;
  typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

The `NSNumber` class allows the encapsulation of primitive types (`int`, `float`, etc.) into an object, which can then be stored into Property Lists and Core Data.

Example:

```
float pi = 3.1415;
NSNumber *piNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:pi];
```

You can then easily access and/or transform the value stored into the `NSNumber` object:

```
int piAsInteger = [piNumber intValue];
```

Comment: A reasonable answer - but not for this particular question.

Comment: Yes, it is. Core Data only holds *objects*, which is why the `NSNumber` class is required. There is no other alternative without unreliable third-party utilities, which can break with any update.

Comment: He asked if he could skip NSNumber and use NSInteger. The answer is no, because you can only store objects in core data. A description of how NSNumber encapsulates values is superfluous. And if someone else disagrees with me they are free to upvote your answer.

Comment: I think a) you need to reread the question - he's already using NSNumber, he wonders if he can skip it. An explanation is off-topic (IMHO and i've voted accordingly) b) you shouldn't be so sensitive to downvotes. I didn't find your answer useful so I downvoted it. Anyone else is welcome to make their own voting decisions.

Comment: a) I answered that question in the first two sentences. Showing the implementation of `NSInteger` was proof to back up that answer. b) I am not sensitive to downvotes, only downvotes without proper reasoning.

Comment: So, you answer is explaining difference between NSInteger and NSNumber, but I've already knew that. And I asked how can i skip NSNumber, not what the difference between them.

Comment: @Andoriyu: And my first word is No and I explained why. What is so difficult to understand?